# Is it possible to implement automatic error highlighting for Python?

Tags: python, ide, livecoding

Are there any IDEs for Python that support automatic error highlighting (like the Eclipse IDE for Java?) I think it would be a useful feature for a Python IDE, since it would make it easier to find syntax errors. Even if such an editor did not exist, it still might be possible to implement this by automatically running the Python script every few seconds, and then parsing the console output for error messages.

Comment: Since you're already using Eclipse, did you consider trying Eclipse's own Python support, PyDev?

Comment: @abarnert That could be useful, thanks for the suggestion. :)

Answer (score 4):

eclipse+pydev

pycharm

many others ....

Answer (score 1):

If you use VIM or don't have a problem with it, try this extension. https://github.com/klen/python-mode

This is for Emacs as well: https://github.com/gabrielelanaro/emacs-for-python

Also pycharm and eclipse with pydev work fine.

Comment: @JoranBeasley Lol, nah I just use vim for python since it works with Python on cydia.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no flyspell error checker, and only one of the three major linters has a flyspell mode, so emacs really isn't as nice for this case as it could be. (If I'm wrong, I'd love to know about alternatives! Not that flyflakes isn't great, it's just that I want more. What's the point of having emacs if you can still count the number of packages you've installed?)

Comment: @JoranBeasley: `vi` and `emacs` are for wimps; if you really can't do all your editing with `cat`, `awk`, and `sed`, you can use `ed`, but only if no one is watching.

Answer (score 1):

If I don't use vim I really enjoy [spyder](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/). It is easy to use and has some really nice features, like integrated debugging and profiling, graphical variable explorer and object inspector. The latter shows, e.g., the integrated documentation for every function of class you use.

Answer (score 1):

I built an extension to Eclipse and PyDev that does what you describe, it runs the Python code as you're typing, and displays all the variable values and any exceptions that occur. It's called [Live Coding in Python](http://donkirkby.github.io/live-py-plugin/), and the web site has a tutorial and a demo video.

PyDev can highlight some problems in your code by analysing it, and Live Coding in Python can show you problems that happen when you run it.